# What's wrong with my nagios kdc configuration?

Tags: nagios, kerberos

I want to setup a service to check the kdc with nagios.
With my kdc (samba4) I create the user using this script

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=nagioskerberos
DOMAIN=myhost.priv
SERVICE=nagioskerberos
FQDN=nagios1.myhost.priv

samba-tool user delete $USER
samba-tool user create $USER --random-password
samba-tool user setexpiry $USER --noexpiry
net ads enctypes set $USER 16
samba-tool spn add $SERVICE/$FQDN $USER
samba-tool domain exportkeytab $USER.keytab --principal=$SERVICE/$FQDN
```

then I copy the keytab on nagios server and restart service

```
scp nagioskerberos.keytab nagios1:
ssh nagios1
systemctl restart nagios
```

the permissions are ok

```
ls -lhd /etc/nagios/nagios.*tab
-rw------- 1 nagios nagios 101 Jul  2 02:25 /etc/nagios/nagios.keytab
```

the keys seems ok

```
klist -ke /etc/nagios/nagios.keytab 
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/nagios/nagios.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2 nagioskerberos/nagios1.myhost.priv@MYHOST.PRIV (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

But when I try to check...

```
./check_kdc -k /etc/nagios/nagios.keytab  -p nagioskerberos/nagios1.myhost.priv@MYHOST.PRIV -H samba4 -P 88
CRITICAL Getting Kerberos ticket: kinit: Client 'nagioskerberos/nagios1.myhost.priv@MYHOST.PRIV' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials (credentials for nagioskerberos/nagios1.myhost.priv@MYHOST.PRIV from /etc/nagios/nagios.keytab)
```

Why?

This is the krb5.conf for server samba4 and server nagios

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MYHOST.PRIV
    dns_lookup_realm = true
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
    permitted_encryptes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

First I change my script

from

```
net ads enctypes set $USER 16
```

to

```
net ads enctypes set $USER 24
```

I recreate the user.

BEFORE export the tab and copy I did this

```
samba-tool user edit nagioskerberos
```

modify this line

```
userPrincipalName: nagioskerberos/nagios1.myhost.priv@MYHOST.PRIV
```

exit..

Copy the keytab, restart nagios and...

```
./check_kdc -k /etc/nagios/nagios.keytab -p nagioskerberos/nagios1.myhost.priv@MYHOST.PRIV -H samba4 -P 88
OK
```